# Replace string in .docx with value from Excel, retaining Excel capitalization

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm writing a macro (in excel) that uses .docx template and replaces strings with the values from excel file. Everything works fine except the fact that the format of pasted value is the same as of replaced string (in this case all pasted value is in uppercase), not the value format from excel. How could I change this code so the pasted value will keep its' format from excel?

```
Sub fromexcel()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("\\xxxxx\Template.docx")
objWord.Visible = True
objDoc.Activate

With objDoc.Range.Find


If ws.Range("B13").Value <> "" Then

objDoc.FormFields(3).CheckBox.Value = True

      .Text = "AAAAA"
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.Text = ws.Range("B13").Value
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Else:
      .Text = "AAAAA"
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End If
```

I tried different combinations with or without ".ClearFormatting" and .format = true/false but nothing seems to work.

Comment: why not just use mail merge? Or make the `AAAA` in word proper case as well.

Comment: Sounds like very odd behavior to me.. are you sure the text in the word document isn't in a font that only has upper-case lettering?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Apologies that I didn't mention it earlier. I cannot change "AAAA" text this way as sometimes copied value is "Name Surname", sometimes it is "Name Surname and Name Surname" etc. so keeping e.g. only first letter in uppercase does not help

Comment: @CLR I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. I use standard Arial font so I don't think this is the problem

Comment: You did understand me correctly. Some fonts present lower case as upper case but Arial isn't one of them. At least you've ruled that out.

Comment: In the Word document, click in the word that is all upper case. Open the FONT dialog box and check whether "All caps" is activated? If yes, that's the cause. And you can correct it by adding (typed from memory) something like: `Replacement.Font.AllCaps = False`

Comment: @CindyMeister No, this field is not checked

Comment: Nothing else occurs to me, but some additional info: the Find and Replace ClearFormatting and Format commands only affect the Find/Replace settings, not what's in the document. For example, if a previous Find used Font.Italics = true as a search criteria, ClearFormatting removes that search criteria. Format = true means the search will look at your Format settings or Replace will use the Format settings. But format in the document, itself, will only change if you've got something in .Replacement.Font (or other).